# ¿Cómo usar el verbo "ignorar" sin ser ambiguo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En una [noticia](http://www.semana.com/nacion/articulo/masacre-de-las-bananeras-historiadora-le-contesta-a-maria-fernanda-cabal/548923) se puede leer:

> La representante a la Cámara se queda también con la versión oficial, publicada en El Tiempo el 6 de diciembre de 1928, según la cual los huelguistas abandonaron la vía pacífica y optaron por vías de hecho, “forzando” al ejército a intervenir. **Ignora**, de nuevo, la congresista Cabal, que el mismo Jefe Civil y militar de la Provincia de Santa Marta, el General Carlos Cortés Vargas, enviado por el presidente Miguel Abadía a lidiar con el conflicto, señalaba apenas un día antes de la masacre que “la organización de los huelguistas era sorprendente” y “aunque armados de machetes ni huyen ni atacan, pero rodean las tropas con la esperanza de que los oficiales simpaticen con ellos”.

Un poco de contexto: La mencionada congresista Cabal hace unas declaraciones polémicas al negar hechos históricos que están documentados.

Mi pregunta surge al leer la palabra "Ignora" que he resaltado en el texto. Según el DLE:

> [**ignorar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KwHqFub)
>
> Del lat. *ignorāre*.
>
> 1. tr. No saber algo o no tener noticia de ello. Ignoro quién pudo haberlo hecho.
> 2. tr. No hacer caso de algo o de alguien, o tratarlos como si no merecieran atención. Me duele que me ignore. Ignora sus comentarios.

Con esto, el texto tiene dos interpretaciones:

1. La congresista no sabe que el general Cortés ha dicho algo específico (“la organización de los huelguistas era sorprendente”)
2. La congresista sabe del hecho pero intencionalmente lo ignora porque va en contravía de sus declaraciones.

Un poco más de contexto: la congresista ha hecho en el pasado declaraciones ( [[Video] María Fernanda Cabal dice que la Unión Soviética hace parte de la ONU](http://www.pulzo.com/nacion/maria-fernanda-cabal-dice-union-sovietica-es-onu/PP294817) ) que hacen más dificil determinar si el sentido del texto es decir que ella no sabe algo o que intencionalmente lo ignora.

¿Existe una manera en español de eliminar esa ambigüedad en el significado de "ignorar"?

Yo pensé que "desconocer" sería una alternativa para cuando se quiere usar solamente el primer significado (el de no saber algo). Sin embargo veo en el DLE:

> [**desconocer**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ci8Sd5K)
>
> 2. tr. No conocer.
> 3. tr. Darse por desentendido de algo, o afectar que se ignora.

O sea que también tiene las dos connotaciones que "ignorar".

Comment: creo que ignorar se debe usar cuando ambas opciones pueden ser validas, cuando estas "ignorando" por no saber o por no considerarlo 

lo que quiero decir es que la ambiguedad del ignorar puede existir solamente cuando ambos terminus pueden ser correctamente interpretados

Comment: Para mí, sin un contexto propicio, ambos verbos están condenados a la ambigüedad.

Comment: Es más: puedes agregar "omitir" a la lista.

Comment: Tangencial, pero: observo una cosa extraña, que es que si digo *ella ignoró* quiero seguramente decir "ella no hizo caso", pero si digo *ella ignoraba* es más probable que quiera decir "ella no sabía". Algo más se esconde atrás de eso.

Comment: "sinonimo tangencial" creo que acabas de inventar in termino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la segunda acepción, yo añadiría el adverbio "conscientemente" para no dejar lugar a dudas:

> *La congresista **ignora*** **conscientemente** *que...*

De esa manera dejamos claro que la congresista es *consciente* de que está ignorando las palabras del general (y por tanto queda excluida la posibilidad de que no las conociese):

> **[consciente](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=ANybMv4)**.
>   Del lat. *consciens, -entis*, part. act. de *conscīre* 'saber perfectamente'.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene conocimiento de algo o se da cuenta de ello, especialmente de los propios actos y sus consecuencias. *Consciente de su error.*

Comment: Si hay un "downvote" estaría bien explicar por qué es. Puede no ser evidente, especialmente para este usuario, que es nuevo en la comunidad, por qué recibe un negativo. Aparte, los comentarios pueden ser usados para [animar/ayudar a] mejorar los post de otros. Pablo, bienvenido a Spanish.se